# How does imap SEARCH work on Microsoft Exchange with python imaplib?

Tags: python, exchange-server, imap, imaplib

My goal is to get a list of e-mails received since a certain date from a Microsoft exchange sever using imaplib in python.
So far I've found out that Exchange does not support the `sort` command. But `search` does not work too well either: There are only a couple of search arguments that do work as they are supposed to, such as the `FROM` keyword. But for my program I need to read the dates and I've tried all related keywords I could find on the internet:
'ON' and 'SINCE' lead to the following error message: `imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Command Argument Error. 11']` which I suppose means Exchange doesn't support them.
'DATE' throws a different exception: `imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'The specified message set is invalid.']` which I suppose means the server does support `DATE` in general but can't handle my data. Therefore I tried several date formats because I don't know which one is expected by the server:
`"2021-07-17"` which as far as I know should be the normal format
`"2021-Jul-17"` `"17-Jul-2021"` and `"17-07-2021"` but all of them lead to the same error message shown prior.
This is my code, maybe I just sent the data in the wrong way? :

```
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imapserver)
imap.login(username, pwd)
status, messages = imap.select(folder)
print(imap.search(None, '(DATE "07-Jul-2021")'))
```

Now my questions are the following:

1. Are my assumptions correct that the two error messages mean "not supported" and "supported but wrong syntax"?
2. Is there any way to see the allowed search arguments?
3. What date format does the server expect? (This question has been answered, ty)
4. Is the syntax of my code correct? '(DATE "07-Jul-2021")'
5. If none of these is the reason my program isn't working - what do I do wrong in order to get e-mails since a certain date?

Any answers to those questions would help me with my confusion, thank you very much ;)

Comment: The reference for search formats is [RFC 3501](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501). The date format is in the section 9 formal syntax, and breaks down to: "02-Mar-2021", the months are spelled out in specific three letter abbreviations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It doesn't solve my problem, but at least it's one problem less now.

Comment: Using the correct date format will help.  No date searches will work if you just guess :)

Comment: I'm not gonna do the wrong date format again, still my program doesn't work and I don't know why ("The specified message set is invalid.")

Comment: I'm not sure why it's still unhappy though I'd try dropping the parenthesis.

Comment: I tried that. According to the official [imaplib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.search) , there are two possibilities when using search: `'FROM', '"LDJ"'` and `'(FROM "LDJ")'` , both of which run into the same error.

Comment: It's unhappy because of the incorrect quoting. Just DATE 07-Jul-2021 would work. mrc used quoting only where there was reason to, and [date-text is a plain old BNF production](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#page-84), quoting would achieve nothing. BTW, I completely agree about the syntax guesswork.

Comment: @arnt I'm sorry to disappoint you, but `imap.search(None, 'DATE 07-Jul-2021')` also runs into the same error

Comment: Ah, yes, I should have reread the spec. [`senton 19-jul-2021`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501#page-52) works, `sentbefore`, `on`, `since` etc ditto. "date" was a plausible guess I suppose.

Comment: @arnt thank you, that actually works!

Comment: Try my lib https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools, it let you work with mailbox, not with RFC